# Value changes to non UTF8 in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I got an jQuery form made with Uniform css/js.

In the dropdown list i got this:
word 1,
word 2,
word 3,
word 4 & 5

When i select the 'word 4 & 5' the value gets changed to `&amp;` instead of &. So when you open de dropdown everything is fine and the & is shown, but when you select it changes to     `&amp;`

How can i solve this problem?

The code is to large to post, so i post the link to the JS
http://uniformjs.com/

Comment: Please show some markup and describe what you have tried to do to fix this.

Comment: The script is from: http://uniformjs.com/ Its to large to post, i tried to set the UTF8 charset, but still, when i select an option it changes to & amp;

Answer (score 0):

Please provide some example code, put it into a JSFiddle if you feel its to much for here. 
I looked into Uniform CSS and i cant see any issues there, it seems to be related with something else, so also provide with Versions you use of Uniform & jQuery. (Maybe even the Browser)

But as said, nobody is able to help you without code.